# EmguCV - Fisheye Calibration

Tags: c#, python, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

For a school project, I am trying to calibrate a Dahua IP Camera, which has Fisheye distortion.
We need to calibrate the camera to undistort the image, because we need a flat image to do image processing.

So far, we have managed to do the calibration in Python with OpenCV, but the rest of the script is written in C#, so we would like to convert the code to C# using the EmguCV wrapper (OpenCV for .NET)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but so far I have done these steps:

- I took 50 pictures of a Chessboard Grid, which is used to find the Corners
- I let OpenCV calculate the correct matrices, one called CameraMatrix and the other is the Distortion Coëfficiënts.
- With the 2 calculated matrices, we then Undistort an image, and the result is a flat image with no distortion.

In Python, this code works. I get 2 matrices that works to undistort.
I tried to copy these matrices in C#, without doing the rest of the Calibration. Since it's the same camera setup, the Distortion should be the same.
However, when I try to hardcode the matrices, the result is not what I want.

Could it be an issue related to EmguCV (The wrapper of OpenCV for .NET), or is it something related to my code?

**Python Code**

```
img = cv2.imread(filename)
K = np.array(...) # removed for brevity
D = np.array(...) # removed for brevity
DIM = (width, height) # image resolution
map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
undistorted_img = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

**C# code**

```
Matrix<double> cameraMatrix = new Matrix<double>(3, 3);
Matrix<double> distortionCoeffs = new Matrix<double>(4, 1);
Mat outputMap1 = new Mat();
Mat outputMap2 = new Mat();
Mat r = new Mat(); // Can be empty, according to the documentation
Mat p = new Mat(); // Can be empty, according to the documentation
Fisheye.InitUndistorRectifyMap(cameraMatrix, distortionCoeffs, r, p, image.Size, DepthType.Cv32F, outputMap1, outputMap2);
CvInvoke.Remap(image, undistorted, outputMap1, outputMap2, Inter.Linear, BorderType.Constant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing the answer hoping this will help someone

I was trying to do exactly like this, first generated the K & D using Python, then undistort the fisheye image in Google Colab following this https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0

then wanted to do the same in C# code using OpenCVSharp.
After trying for almost one day, I was finally able to come up with a working code which is as follows.

C# Code that works for me

```
        OpenCvSharp.Size DIM = new OpenCvSharp.Size(1280, 1024);
        Mat K = new Mat(3, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[,] { { 411.23914063230376, 0.0, 625.1291183561409 }, { 0.0, 411.64580081704975, 493.39384657887706 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 } });
        Mat D = new Mat(4, 1, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[,] { { 0.004481730916688151 }, { 0.018118651707822304 }, { -0.010641336952383246 }, { 0.001460032817948352 } });

        // Initialize undistortion map
        Mat map1 = new Mat(), map2 = new Mat();
        Cv2.FishEye.InitUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, Mat.Eye(3, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1), K, DIM, MatType.CV_16SC2, map1, map2);

        // Load the fish-eye image
        Mat imgFishEye = Cv2.ImRead("fisheye/1.bmp");

        // Undistort the fish-eye image
        Mat undistortedImg = new Mat();
        Cv2.Remap(imgFishEye, undistortedImg, map1, map2, InterpolationFlags.Linear, BorderTypes.Constant);

        // Display the undistorted image
        Cv2.ImShow("Undistorted Image", undistortedImg);
```